# Series of functions as Lebesgue integral with counting measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ for $n=1,2,...$. Then

\begin{equation}\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n = \int_{\mathbb{N}}f_n\text{ d}\mu
\end{equation}
where $\mu$ is counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$.

I seem to not be able to prove this. Note that where are not summing values of $f$ at points in $\mathbb{N}$ but summing functions itself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are integrating with respect to $n$, so you want to view $f_{n}(x)=: f(x,n)$ as a function of $n$.

Comment: How can you do that if each $f_n$ is a entirely different function?